# Is it called Polymorphism when not using a parent class in PHP?

Tags: php, c++, polymorphism

In C++, if I want to use Polymorphism, I would create a parent class and then derive many child classes from the parent class, and then I would be able to assign an address of a child class object to a pointer variable of the parent class.

For example: say that I have a parent class called `Animal`, and then I derived two child classes from `Animal`, which are `Dog` and `Cat`, and the three classes have a method called `speak()`.

Now I can create a function that takes `Animal*` as argument:

```
void foo(Animal* animal)
{
    animal->speak();
}
```

And do the following:

```
Cat *cat = new Cat();
Dog *dog = new Dog();
foo(cat);
foo(dog);
```

---

But in PHP, a variable can be of any type, so even if I don't have a parent `Animal` class and only have a `Cat` and a `Dog` class, I can still do the following:

```
function foo($animal)
{
    $animal->speak();
}

$cat = new Cat();
$dog = new Dog();
foo($cat);
foo($dog);
```

So is it still called Polymorphism when not using a parent class?

Comment: Can't say since I don't know about PHP but this sounds more like the template concept in C++ where you would have `template <typename Animal> void foo(Animal& animal) { animal.speak(); }`

Comment: Inheritance-based polymorphism is only one kind of polymorphism to begin with. The name doesn't tie itself to a specific programmatic construct.

Comment: php is like python, in that it is not strongly-typed language. Instead you have what is sometimes called duck-typing. I do not think inheritance-based polymorphism concept is applied to duck-typing languages.

Comment: If you put your cursor over the polymorphism tag below your question, you will get a neat concise definition of polymorphism. This construct fits that definition.

Comment: Just because you can it doesn't mean this is the recommended way to do it. Create a [base class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) for the `Cat` and `Dog` classes if you feel it's appropriate or just an [interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) (and let both classes [implement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php#language.oop5.interfaces.implements) it) and use it to declare the [type of the `$animal` argument](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration).

Answer (score 1):

The sort of polymorphism you're describing in C++ is *subtyping* (the third in the list of three distinct meanings in [this linked Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science))).

This is also described (at least in statically-typed languages like C++) as dynamic polymorphism since the point is that the "dynamic" (runtime) type of your object varies from the "static" compile-time type of the interface.

What you're discussing in PHP is [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), which is essentially a form of parametric polymorphism.

This is roughly equivalent to the static polymorphism you get from templates in C++, although the implementation is obviously very different.

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism is a concept that's pretty abstract and in particular independent of any particular implementation. In that sense, yes, your code uses polymorphism.

Now, concerning your comparison with C++, you are comparing apples with oranges here. The following piece of PHP is much closer to the C++ code:

```
function foo(Animal $animal)
{
    $animal->speak();
}
```

On the other hand, you can also adjust the C++ code:

```
template<typename animal_type>
void foo(animal_type& animal)
{
    animal.speak();
}
```

Note that I have fixed the non-idiomatic use of pointers by your version, but the important part is that the function is now a template.